# Accept a Keypress independent of the VB.Net Form

Tags: vb.net, keyboard

I have created a simple VB.Net Windows Form application to demonstrate a class hierarchy using Tic Tac Toe - player strategies that build on each other. I want to allow a Human to play, so I need to get a value from the keypad: 1-9 to indicate position. I don't want a form field or elaborate hook schemes and so on. Is there an equivalent of the Console ReadKey ability that I can use?

Comment: It would be fun to be able to post what I have so far. I have player strategies for Idiot (random), Naive (choose center, corners then edges, with weighted randomness), then Block (detects when the other player has two in a row, otherwise uses Naive) and Winner (attempts to Win itself, or uses Blocker strategy), and last of all, Human (keypress). I have all this working nicely. Thinking of building a Tournament App to produce a grid of All against All. (Moving first gives an advantage. Also, if there was no randomness in the Naive strategy, it would be completely predictable every time.)

Answer (score 0):

Set your Form's `KeyPreview`property to True and then parse the results in the Form's `KeyUp`event.

Comment: I will look in to your suggestion, but I am operating outside the Event paradigm in this case: literally attempting to wait for a key to be pressed, and I don't see how the Form can provide that. In my player strategy procedural code, how do I have a statement that says "Then a Miracle (keypress) Occurs" ? At the moment, I am using an InputBox to get the keypress, but even that should not be there.

Answer (score 0):

Override `ProcessCmdKey()` like this:

```
Public Class Form1

    Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, keyData As Keys) As Boolean
        Select Case keyData
            Case Keys.Home
                Debug.Print("7")

            Case Keys.Up
                Debug.Print("8")

            Case Keys.PageUp
                Debug.Print("9")

            Case Keys.Left
                Debug.Print("4")

            Case Keys.Clear
                Debug.Print("5")

            Case Keys.Right
                Debug.Print("6")

            Case Keys.End
                Debug.Print("1")

            Case Keys.Down
                Debug.Print("2")

            Case Keys.PageDown
                Debug.Print("3")

        End Select
        Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
    End Function

End Class
```

---------- Edit ----------

> Can I call on this and it will wait for a keypress? –  no comprende
>
> Not in this form, no. One way to do this, however, would be to have the game loop running in another THREAD and then make it block
>   while waiting for a ManualResetEvent to be set. I'll update with a
>   short example when I get back home. –  Idle_Mind

Here's a quick example with a **simulated** TicTacToe game:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Selection As Integer = -1
    Private MRE As New ManualResetEvent(False)

    Private Sub btnStartGame_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStartGame.Click
        btnStartGame.Enabled = False
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
        Dim TTT As New TicTacToe
        While Not TTT.GameOver

            UpdateLabel("Computer Thinking...")
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)

            TTT.ComputerMove()
            UpdateLabel("Computer Moved")
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)

            GetHumanMove("Use the KeyPad to indicate your move!")

            TTT.HumanMove(Selection)
            UpdateLabel("Move Selected: " & Selection)
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)

        End While
        e.Result = TTT.Result
    End Sub

    Private Sub UpdateLabel(ByVal msg As String)
        Label1.Invoke(Sub()
                          Label1.Text = msg
                      End Sub)
    End Sub

    Private Sub GetHumanMove(ByVal msg As String)
        UpdateLabel(msg)
        MRE.Reset()
        MRE.WaitOne()
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, keyData As Keys) As Boolean
        Select Case keyData
            Case Keys.Home
                Selection = 7
                MRE.Set()

            Case Keys.Up
                Selection = 8
                MRE.Set()

            Case Keys.PageUp
                Selection = 9
                MRE.Set()

            Case Keys.Left
                Selection = 4
                MRE.Set()

            Case Keys.Clear
                Selection = 5
                MRE.Set()

            Case Keys.Right
                Selection = 6
                MRE.Set()

            Case Keys.End
                Selection = 1
                MRE.Set()

            Case Keys.Down
                Selection = 2
                MRE.Set()

            Case Keys.PageDown
                Selection = 3
                MRE.Set()

        End Select

        Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
    End Function

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
        Dim result As String = e.Result
        MessageBox.Show(result, "Game Over!")
        btnStartGame.Enabled = True
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class TicTacToe

    Private MoveCounter As Integer

    Public ReadOnly Property GameOver As Boolean
        Get
            Return MoveCounter = 6
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub ComputerMove()
        MoveCounter = MoveCounter + 1
    End Sub

    Public Sub HumanMove(ByVal selection As Integer)
        MoveCounter = MoveCounter + 1
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Result As String
        Get
            Return "Draw"
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Comment: Can I call on this and it will wait for a keypress?

Comment: Not in this form,  no.  One way to do this, however,  would be to have the game loop running in another THREAD and then make it block while waiting for a ManualResetEvent to be set.  I'll update with a short example when I get back home.